# How to get an "ORDER BY" style of sorting in Java?

Tags: sql-order-by

I have a class for example Person.

```
public class Person {
    private Integer age;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
   // getters and setters
}
```

I want to sort this in the ORDER BY style, which is provided by SQL queries. Collections.sort(listOfPersons, ) should return me data in this fashion.
"SELECT * FROM PERSONS ORDER BY AGE, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement your own `Comparator` would do, like:

```
Collections.sort(listOfPerson, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please give me an hint of what to be written in compare() method?